# Rails 3 Form Remote Not Working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

My ajaxy calls weren't working, then it randomly started working, then it stopped working when I added more coffeescript.  I removed the added coffeescript and still, no worky.

I noticed that `rails.js` isn't being loaded (via inspection by firebug/Chrome inspector). Has `rails.js` been replaced by `jquery_ujs.js` in rails 3.2.1? I started a new project and noticed that `rails.js` wasn't there either.

Here's the form:

```
<%= form_tag("#{tybleau_api_path}.json", remote: true, id: "sportForm", :'data-type' => 'json' ) do%>
    <%= select_tag("state", options_from_collection_for_select(@states, "HometownState", "HometownState"), prompt: "Choose a State", class: "submittable") %>
    <%= submit_tag "Update View" %>
<% end %>
```

The console is showing this when I click "Update View":

```
Started POST "/tybleau/api.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-22 17:40:03 -0700
Processing by TybleauController#api as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"I6752Fit6cCIuASMr4/FD+yLTEBrS2oPhnNBbJQE67k=", "state"=>"AZ", "commit"=>"Update View"}
  Player Load (745.1ms)  SELECT FirstName FROM `players` INNER JOIN `players_to_teams` ON `players_to_teams`.`player_id` = `players`.`id` INNER JOIN `teams` ON `teams`.`id` = `players_to_teams`.`team_id` WHERE `teams`.`SportTypeId` = 2 AND `players`.`hometownstate` = 'AZ'
  EXPLAIN (0.4ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT FirstName FROM `players` INNER JOIN `players_to_teams` ON `players_to_teams`.`player_id` = `players`.`id` INNER JOIN `teams` ON `teams`.`id` = `players_to_teams`.`team_id` WHERE `teams`.`SportTypeId` = 2 AND `players`.`hometownstate` = 'AZ'
EXPLAIN for: SELECT FirstName FROM `players` INNER JOIN `players_to_teams` ON `players_to_teams`.`player_id` = `players`.`id` INNER JOIN `teams` ON `teams`.`id` = `players_to_teams`.`team_id` WHERE `teams`.`SportTypeId` = 2 AND `players`.`hometownstate` = 'AZ'
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                          | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | players_to_teams | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                         | 260239 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | players          | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | mysql_development.players_to_teams.player_id |      1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | teams            | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | mysql_development.players_to_teams.team_id   |      1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------------------+--------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Completed 200 OK in 1034ms (Views: 154.7ms | ActiveRecord: 825.9ms)
```

So I know it's working.  If I remove the call to `remote: true`, I get the expected result as a json object.

Here's my coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
  $("#sportForm")
  .bind 'ajax:beforeSend', (xhr, settings) ->
    alert 'loading'
  .bind 'ajax:success', (data, status, xhr) ->
    alert 'success'
  .bind 'ajac:complete', (xhr, status) ->
    alert 'success'
  .bind 'ajax:error', (xhr, status, error) ->
    alert 'error'
```

Is there a typo or something in there? Should rails.js be viewable in firebug?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with SlickGrid.  Either SlickGrid or one of the required jQuery-UI libraries was having some naming problem and was stealing the focus of the ajax responses.  I've decided to use something other than SlickGrid, so I never fully diagnosed the problem, but it's working nothing.

**Note**

In Rails 3.2.1, there is no `rails.js`, it's `jquery_ujs.js`.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

rails.js should be visible in firebug, if it is not visible it is not being requested by the browser.  There must be an issue with your layout or your javascript manifest file that is preventing rails.js from being loaded.

in Rails 3.1+, make sure:

1. **Gemfile** contains:

   `gem 'jquery-ujs'`

   *(add it and run `bundle` if you don't)*
2. **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb** contains:

   `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`
3. **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** containts:

   `//= jquery`

   `//= jquery-ujs`

   *(assuming you're using the asset pipeline)*

If that is the case, you should see `jquery.js` and `jquery_ujs.js` in Firebug, or in the page source when you load the page.

Comment: Has rails.js been replaced by `jquery_ujs.js`?  I started  new project, and `rails.js` wasn't there either.

Comment: rails.js resides in the jquery-ujs project, see [jquery-ujs on github](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/tree/master/src).  The file in your application will be rails.js.  If it doesn't already exist, add jquery-rails to your Gemfile to get it.  You will need to be sure rails.js is included in your template via javascript_include_tag or via your application.js manifest file.

Comment: well, that may be incorrect, checkout the Installation section of the readme on the [jquery-ujs repo](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).  Under Rails 3.1 it metions adding:
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
to your manifest

Comment: You did the work, figured you deserved the bounty.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: thanks Tyler, I modified my answer above to relfect jquery_ujs.js, rather than rails.js.  I hope that didn't send on a wild goose chase!

Comment: Could not find gem 'jquery-ujs (>= 0) ruby'